# How to plot "multiple" curves with a break through y-data-range in R?

Tags: r, plot

The function `gap.plot` in package `plotrix` is used to plot graphs where one wants to place a gap in either the y or x axis. However, I can't seem to add curves to the plot. Here is a toy reproducible example.

```
xx = c(100, 10,9,8,7,0)
yy = c(88, 9,9,7,7,7)
tt = 1:6;
gapxy = c(12, 85)
gap.plot(tt, xx, gap=gapxy, ylim=c(0,100), ytics=c(1:11, 86:100) )
lines(tt, yy)
```

The key issue here is the `yy` data and `xx` data have values that would lie in the gap. This causes warning messages. However, even more concerning, the `yy` variable has a maximum value of 88, but adding `yy` to the gap plot gives it a maximum value going off the page. Is there anyway to correct for this. I am not necessarily stuck to using gap plot, but do require we stick to the base package no ggplot2 solutions please. I have tried replacing lines with a second gap.plot call with `add = T` as a option, as suggested in the documentation, but this results in the top half of yy not plotting.

```
gap.plot(tt, yy, gap=gapxy, add=T, type='l', ylim=c(0,100))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the lines do not appear as they should is that `gap.plot` doesn't set up the coordinate system properly, as can be seen with

```
> par("usr")
[1]  0.80  6.20 -1.08 28.08
```

Meaning the x-axis ranges between `[0.8, 6.2]` as it should but the y-axis ranges between `[-1.08, 28.08]` even though the plot makes it look like it goes all the way to 100.

Rather than using `gap.plot` I recommend you set up a two-panel-plot with the standard tools of R. It requires more code, but get's it right under the hood.

```
par(mfrow=2:1, mar=rep(.5, 4), oma=c(3,3,1,1))
plot(tt, xx, ylim=c(86, 100), axes=FALSE)
axis(2); box()
lines(tt, yy)
plot(tt, xx, ylim=c(1, 11))
lines(tt, yy)
```

[image: Plot with split y-axis]

Comment: works like a charm ... nothing like going back to the basics instead of trying to torture packages to do things they weren't intended.

Comment: Yeah, you can do a lot of stuff that looks very fancy by just controlling panels and margins, so be sure to check out `mar` and `oma` if you aren't familiar with them already.

Comment: And for those plots that require different top and bottom panels using the option `fig` wtih `new=TRUE` for each panel individually instead of `mfrow`!