# How to create an x axis break on the density plot?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to do a density plot of a dataset that has a wide range.

> data=c(-10,-20,-20,-18,-17,1000,10000, 500, 500, 500, 500000)
>
> plot(density(data))

As you can see in the figure, we can not see much
[image].

Is there a way to make an axis break (or several ones) on the x axis to visualise better the distribution of the data? Or, is there a way to plot a certain range of the data in several graphs and than paste it together?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `gap.plot()` in package `plotrix` but I think it has some problems (see [How to plot “multiple” curves with a break through y-data-range in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825436/how-to-plot-multiple-curves-with-a-break-through-y-data-range-in-r)). I recommend you draw two plots.

```
  ## use small margins and relatively big outer margins (to write labels).
old.par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2), mar = rep(0.5, 4), oma = c(4, 4, 1, 1))

plot(density(data), xlim = c(-1000, 29000), main = "", bty="c")               # diff 30000
abline(v = par("usr")[2], lty=2)          # keep the same diff of xlim to avoid misleading
plot(density(data), xlim = c(471000, 501000), main = "", yaxt ="n", bty="]")  # diff 30000
abline(v = par("usr"[1]), lty=2)

par(old.par)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that helps @cuttlefish44